# Find where sscanf finished reading the string

Tags: c, scanf

I am using `sscanf` in a simple little project. However, I can't see any obvious way to find where in the input string that `sscanf` decided it found all of its data and stopped processing.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think %n is what you are looking for.

Example:

```
sscanf("123", "%d%n", &i, &count);
```

This will store 3 in `count'.

Comment: That is **extremely interesting**. It doesn't seem to be standard though, can you point me to some documentation ?

Comment: After some searching for sscanf n, found a reference to that... not yet tried it but thanks!

Comment: This is the C Standard Library reference I use: http://www.utas.edu.au/infosys/info/documentation/C/CStdLib.html

Comment: `"%n"` is compliant with the Standard. Check 7.19.6.2 in [the lastest publically available version of the C99 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

See "%n" format specifier in http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/io/c/sscanf

Comment: That looks like a fairly solid reference site, not sure why I haven't stumbled upon it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The return value on `sscanf` is the number of items that were successfully converted.